# RNFirebase In-app Messaging - How to handle button clicks

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

Hi I'm using the latest version of react native in-app messaging and I need to handle the button clicks. Can someone help me with this

[image]

Comment: code what u trying to do ?

Comment: I have designed the ui in firebase console and its displaying in mobile. When I click on the share button I want to redirect to a page or. have to open a webview

Comment: You can follow simple workflow like this:
1. Add custom data in notification `payload`
2. Handle click button event to open webview with page_url from `payload`.
Try each steps and check where you got stuck.

Comment: @ThinhPhan how can I handle payload for in-app message?

Answer (score 0):

You should use deeplinks.
Setup deeplink like `myapp://do_something`
Then in firebase console add same action for the button.
When you press button, deeplinks listener will be triggered